# Object array: reference to existing objects or new instances

Tags: javascript, pointers, object

I have the following struct (or class?) in JavaScript:

```
function ImageStruct() {
    this.id = -1;
    this.isCover = true;
    this.isPaired = false;
    this.row = -1;
    this.column = -1;
}
```

I add this class to a bidimensional array.

```
var imgStruct = new ImageStruct();
imgStruct.id = id;
imgStruct.row = row;
imgStruct.column = column;

$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column] = imgStruct;
```

When I do something like this:

```
var imgStrc = $.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column];
```

If I modify `imgStrc`, object in `$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column]` doesn't reflect that changes.

Is there any way to 'fix' this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-is-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: `$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column] = imgStrc` again after modifying it.

Comment: @Orbling: I know this is a possible solution, but I want to know if there is another one. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I would also recommend againts treating javaScript like C (by thinking in terms of structs and pointers). it's best to treat JS as a prototyping OO / functional hybrid.

Comment: @Raynos: I didn't explain it very well. I'm trying to say if imgStrc is a reference of an existing object or if it's a new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify `imgStrc` it by changing its properties (e.g. by doing `imgStrc.id = 42`), that change *will* affect the object in `$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column]` (as it is in fact the same object).

Only if you modify `imgStrc` by reassigning it, it won't. There is no way to 'fix' this, other than setting `$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column] = imgStrc` or wrapping the whole thing into a wrapper object (or one-element array).

Answer (score 2):

It definitely should be "by reference".  I set up a JsFiddle to confirm.

http://jsfiddle.net/bJaL4/

Structs aren't really possible in JavaScript.  There are explicit value and reference types.  All objects are treated as reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify the object directly:

```
$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column].someMethod();
```

which is admittedly not very convenient, or feed the value back into the array after modifying it:

```
var tmp = $.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column];

tmp.someMethod(); // Do something...

$.myNameSpace.matrixPos[row][column] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have pointers.  You last var statement just overwrites the imgStrc value with the value of the namespace property.  Whatever that value is is what you modified.  If it's an object, all references to that obj will see the change.